# Improving myopia

Tags: human-biology, pathology, vision, human-eye

I have a friend who no longer needs glasses. He previously had myopia in both eyes but over the years it has improved until he no longer needs glasses clinically. He's had glasses for over 30 years since he was around 20.

Based on the above, I'd like to know if myopia can be improved naturally. Specifically whether not using glasses helps the underlying architecture of the visual system compensate in someway, or perhaps if nutrition can reduce myopia or finally if aging is known to decrease myopia. I'm interested in any biological mechanism at play.

I have a good understanding of Opthalmology and additionally would like any answers to be evidence based.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently reduction of myopia with age is fairly common. It is thought that the improved vision comes from relaxation of the ciliary muscle as the person ages. Since the lens changes shape the aberrant myopic focusing of light can be corrected to the correct location. While age was found to be the strongest factor influencing myopia progression, other factors like ethnicity and sex also play a role.
http://archopht.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=417134#

For additional info see:

http://www.iovs.org/content/41/8/2103.long
http://www.improveeyesight.org/can-myopia-near-sightedness-improve-with-age

Comment: Thank you! I read your reference which said improving beyond 1 diopter is rare. Perhaps there are more factors at play or certain factors tilt the balance such as genetics, nutrition etc. Could you explore these also?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an answer based on my personal experience. I know that presbyopia usually increases with aging, so presbyopia and myopia can compensate each other with time. That's maybe what happened to your friend. But I don't know if myopia is related to nutrition or the use of glasses..